# What are the band units of L8C2L2 before applying the scale factor?

Tags: landsat, band, scale-factor

Bellow there is an image which shows "Collection 2 Landsat 8 Level 2 Science Products Band Specifications". When I use the multiplicative scale factor and the additive offset on Band 10, I get the right temperature value in Kelvin. But what is Band's 10 unit, before applying the scale factor and the offset? I have the same doubt for the Reflectance Bands.

[image]